# Uniquely identify SKShapenodes lines as they are drawn

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, swift3

The following code allows me to draw lines on the screen and append them to an array. The problem i have is uniquely naming the lines. Ignore that I used (t) below but I want it to increment the name (sprite1....sprite3) as i draw more lines. Any idea?  fyi I have not added the touched moved method on purpose.

```
var lineNode = SKShapeNode()
var lines: [UITouch: SKShapeNode] = [:]
var lineArray:[SKShapeNode] = []    

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first!
    _ = touch.location(in: self)

    for t in touches {
        self.touchDown(atPoint: t.location(in: self))
        let location: CGPoint = t.location(in: self)

        // Create a mutable path
        let path: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: location)

        // Create a shape node using the path
        let lineNode = SKShapeNode(path: path.cgPath)

        //Name the sprite but this is incorrect as t is touches.
        lineNode.name = "sprite\(t)"
        lineNode.strokeColor = SKColor.yellow
        lineNode.glowWidth = 3.0
        self.addChild(lineNode)

        lines[t] = lineNode

        //Add each SKShapenode to Dictionary
        lineArray.append(lineNode)
    }
}
```

Comment: really? Just use a variable with an incrementor.  Instance variable:`var spriteNameCount = 0` Then `lineNode.name = "sprite\(spriteNameCount)"` finally `spriteNameCount+=1`

Comment: well that seems simple enough.... thanks but i cant help but feel i'm going to come into problems later on. Lets see

Comment: no idea, not sure what you are doing

Comment: You can use `lineArray.count` as the index